# Exacttarget error when creating multiple subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I get a "bad request" error when trying to create multiple subscribers with one call.

This works fine:

```
     var co = new CreateOptions { SaveOptions = new SaveOption[1] };
    co.SaveOptions[0] = new SaveOption { SaveAction = SaveAction.UpdateAdd, PropertyName = "*" };

        try
        {
            string cRequestId;
            string cStatus;
            var apiObj = new APIObject[]{subs[0]};

            //Call the Create method on the Subscriber object
            var cResults = api.Create(co, apiObj, out cRequestId, out cStatus);
            foreach (var ur in cResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Message: " + ur.StatusMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CREATE ERROR:" + ex.Message);
        }
```

This gives an error:

```
 var co = new CreateOptions { SaveOptions = new SaveOption[1] };
        co.SaveOptions[0] = new SaveOption { SaveAction = SaveAction.UpdateAdd, PropertyName = "*" };

        try
        {
            string cRequestId;
            string cStatus;
            var apiObj = new APIObject[]{subs.Count};
            for (var i = 0; i < subs.Count; i++)
            {
                apiObj[i] = subs[i];
            }
            //Call the Create method on the Subscriber object
            var cResults = api.Create(co, apiObj, out cRequestId, out cStatus);
            foreach (var ur in cResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Message: " + ur.StatusMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CREATE ERROR:" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but not with the amount of data I was trying to create initially. If I send 1000 subscribers at once it works, for 5000 it times out.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the corresponding SOAP to verify (found at https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl) but I don't believe you can do a create passing in an array.  You need to do one create at a time.

Comment: the create request is defined this way:  <element name="CreateRequest">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="Options" type="tns:CreateOptions" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
<element name="Objects" type="tns:APIObject" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</sequence>
</complexType> so i guess you can pass multiple apiobjects...also the documentation says you can create one or a batch of objects of different type...